# How to ignore React Navigation state persistence for a nested stack?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've a nested tab navigation with React Navigation and I use AsyncStorage for state persistence of the navigation. What I want to do is ignoring the saving of the state when user opens the nested navigation stack (Programs > ProgramMain/Recipes/Support). Here is my structure:

```
-Home
-Programs
---ProgramMain
---Recipes
---Support
-Profile
```

I tried to inspect passed **state** variable of the NavigationContainer's **onStateChange** but couldn't figure out how can I know which screen/stack is selected.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can use this for mutate the navigation state: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right path and you can find this info in the route property of the state variable passed by NavigationContainer's onStateChange:

Every state object contains a route property (list of route objects), which lists the screens that are rendered in the navigator.

A route object may also contain a state: An optional object containing the navigation state of a child navigator nested inside this screen.

See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-state

[This page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/) shows an example on how to get the active route from a navigator so you know which screen is currently active.

Comment: thank you, *routes* property contains array of nested routes (all of them), so it looks hard to determine when "current" route is on focus. (or I couldn't find a way yet)

Comment: Have you seen [this page of the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/)? It has an example on how to get the active route from a navigator so you know which screen is currently active.

Comment: I haven't seen this, I solved it with getting list of routes but it seems this doc provides better practice. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. I've added the URL of the example to my answer.